# Get the first character using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm using regex trying to get the first character of a specific word between `(.*?)`

```
About Sildenafil Citrate Phosphodiesterase-5 Enzyme Inhibitor
```

and the regex:

```
Citrate (.*?)Enzyme
```

So I get match `Phosphodiesterase-5`

But I need to get only the first character `P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the capturing group to capturing a single non whitespace char `(\S)` and use word boundaries `\b` :

```
\bCitrate (\S).*? Enzyme\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ipitw/1)

Answer (score 0):

Changing your regex to `Citrate (.).*?Enzyme` would be enough. This captures the first character after "Citrate ".

Answer (score 0):

If your environments supports lookaround you try this pattern

```
(?<=\bCitrate ).(?=.*?Enzyme\b)
```

- `(?<=\bCitrate )` - Positive lookbehind, match must be preceded by `\bCitrate`
- `.` - Match anything expect new line
- `(?=.*?Enzyme\b)` - Positive lookahead, match must be followed by `.*?Enzyme\b`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/p8y5lE/1/)